# ''Rather than vs over''

Tags: grammar

''***Over***'' meaning in longmann dictionary

> Preferring: if you choose one thing over another , you choose that thing rather than the other.

EX:

> What is your main reason for choosing one restaurant ***over*** another?

**Can I make this sentence with ''Rather than'' in the same meaning with ''Over'' ?

> What is your main reason for choosing one restaurant ***rather than*** another?

''***Rather Than***'' definition

> We use rather than to give more importance to one thing when two alternatives or preferences are being compared:

EX:

> He wanted to be an actor rather than a comedian.
>
> Can we come over on Saturday rather than Friday?
>
> Can I make these sentences with ''***over***'' in the same meaning with ''Rather than''?
>
> He wanted to be an actor over a comedian.
>
> Can we come over on Saturday over Friday?

Comment: In my studies i didn't came across any of such expressions like "actor over comedian" or "saturday over friday".   To choose the blue color has more advantages "over" red color for painting a lake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use **rather than**.

These two examples do not seem correct to this native UK English speaker.

> He wanted to be an actor over a comedian.
>
> Can we come over on Saturday over Friday?

This usage of **over** seems acceptable:

> I would choose Brand X over Brand Y

The difference being that we are explicitly using the word **choose**

In my own work I would use

> I would choose Brand X rather than Brand Y
>
> I would choose Brand X in preference to Brand Y

Generally, I would use **rather than** or **in preference to** instead of **over** (or indeed use **instead of**). This may be a matter of personal preference, but for me the word **over** has [so many meanings](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/over) that the chance of ambiguity or clumsiness due to repetition  is too great.

For example look at the two uses of **over** in the same sentence in your example:

> Can we come over on Saturday over Friday?